# Could a civilization go from the end of the stone age to the space age within a couple thousand years?

Tags: society, space-travel, spaceships, science-in-society

I was wondering if it is plausible for a civilization to go from the end of the stone age to the space age from 6,000 years to 10,000 years. I was thinking this planet's star was starting to die, and the civilization had a absolute max of 10,000 years to get off the planet and move to another, hopefully in another solar system.

And if it was not possible, how quickly would they have to move in order to get the space age? Would they have to be significantly more intelligent than humans?

They start getting the fact the sun is dying around the 5,000 year mark. Perhaps some know about this significantly before others, but the impending death of the sun is made common knowledge to all at the 5,000 year mark.

Comment: When do you think stone age has ended?

Comment: Right before the clock I proposed has been started, within a few years.

Comment: Depending on definition of stone age, it likely had ended less than 5000 years ago. Right now we are in what's broadly called "space age", but not yet in interstellar travel age.

Comment: Big problem:  At the end of the stone age they have no idea what the space age is or that it could save them.  Nor can they possibly know the star is dying in 5,000 years.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The civilization has 5,000 years of development until they know about the star, and will progress normally until that point.

Comment: @Alexander: I think OP is referring to the next stone age which the world leader is still making preparations for its launch...

Comment: Well happily enough we seem to have done it so no worries it is definitely possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We seem to be in that ballpark.

Our stone age is considered to have ended between 10,000 and 4000 years ago, and most people who care to speculate think we ought to be ready to move on to other worlds in the next thousand years.

1000 years ago nobody knew there were places other than Earth. If we knew the Earth was going to be destroyed it wouldn't make us work on making rockets it would make us look for divine aid.